# Delete, upon foreign key constraint update

Tags: mysql

MySQL offers the following:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

Does MySQL offer something similar for DELETE which would attempt to delete and upon foreign key constraint, update the record in the table which was attempted to be deleted?

For instance...

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE idtable1 = 123;
IF(foreign key constraint) {  //pseudo code...
  UPDATE table1 SET deleted=1 WHERE idtable1 = 123;
}

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (
  idtable1 INT NOT NULL,
  data VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  deleted TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (idtable1))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 (
  idtable2 INT NOT NULL,
  table1_idtable1 INT NOT NULL,
  data VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  INDEX fk_table2_table1_idx (table1_idtable1 ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_table2_table1
    FOREIGN KEY (table1_idtable1)
    REFERENCES table1 (idtable1)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a cascading foreign constraint on `delete` and/or `update`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 (
  idtable2 INT NOT NULL,
  table1_idtable1 INT NOT NULL,
  data VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  INDEX fk_table2_table1_idx (table1_idtable1 ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_table2_table1
    FOREIGN KEY (table1_idtable1)
    REFERENCES table1 (idtable1)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

This will delete the row in `table2` when the corresponding row in `table1` is deleted.

You can read about the different types of foreign key constraints in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

Comment: Thanks, but no, I don't wish a cascade and do not wish the corresponding record in `table2` to be deleted or updated.  I wish the `ON DELETE` on `table2` to remain `NO ACTION` (or `RESTRICT`), and upon attempting to delete a record in `table1`, update the `deleted` flag in `table1` indicating that it was (kind of) deleted.

Comment: @user1032531 . . . Then use `on delete set null` or `on delete set default`.  The problem is, if you have a foreign key reference, it needs to be to a valid value.  That is the purpose of a foreign key.

Comment: The `deleted` flag is used to tell the application that the user deleted `table1`.  Records in `table1` and `table2` are not really deleted.  Please look at my pseudo code where I showed if delete failed due to foreign key constraint, update this flag.  Maybe a trigger?

Comment: @user1032531 . . . I think you need to do this using a trigger.  You want it to affect *another* column.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought maybe so but was still hoping. I've used triggers before, but never to detect a foreign key constraint.  Do you know how to do this part?